# transforming an absolute value objective function into a linear programming model

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming

I am having a little trouble converting this problem into a linear programming model and how it affects the constraints.

max-z = |2x1 - 3x2|

s.t. 4x1 + x2 <= 4

2x1 - x2 <= 0.5

x1, x2 >= 0

Comment: What is "max-z"?

Comment: it means its a maximisation problem, it isnt related to my question however. I am trying to get rid of the absolute values so it turns into a standard LP model

Comment: You should be aware that this problem can't be formulated as an LP without using integer variables and creating a mixed integer linear programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

For linear programming problems with only two variables you can easily see what the extreme points are by plotting the feasible region onto a plane.

In your case they look to be 
$$
\left \{ (0,0), (0, 4), (\frac{1}{4}, 0) (\frac{3}{4}, 1) \right \}
$$

When you plug those numbers into your objective function you can easily find which points produce the highest result.